# How to find the most terminal points when a set of points is given?

Tags: google-maps

I need to find the most terminal point from the set of points and to draw a polygon through them. The task looks like this:

[image]

1) Red dots are a set of `LatLng` points on the map.

2) I need to identify the most distant of them and to draw a polygon through them (the green line).

It is not hard to draw a polygon if you know coordinates. But I don't know how to identify the most distant points.

**UPD 1:**

For now I've found that there is a name for this task. It is called "[Vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover)".

**UPD 2:**

The task is called "[Convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms)". Here is a visual implementation of the task http://computacion.cs.cinvestav.mx/~anzures/geom/hull.php

Answer (score 1):

You  can compute the convex hull of a set of points with a delaunay triangulation. Then  you can look for all vertexes connected with the supertriangle. You can download my php class convex hull @ phpclasses.org. I also wrote a php class concave  hull. I suggest the concave hull because a country shape isn't always convex. Here is an example:http://www.phpdevpad.de/geofence.